# Error when pip install -e geonode: Getting requirements to build wheel ... error

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, osgeo4w, geonode

I am unsure as to where my current problem is, can someone please point me to my existing problem and possible solution.

```
 (geonode_env) C:\Users\amell\Documents>pip install -e geonode
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
    Obtaining file:///C:/Users/amell/Documents/geonode
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\amell\appdata\local\temp\tmpvsfkgv'
           cwd: C:\Users\amell\Documents\geonode
      Complete output (21 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "c:\users\amell\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-wf0rfk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "c:\users\amell\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-wf0rfk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "c:\users\amell\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-wf0rfk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
          version=__import__("geonode").get_version(),
        File "C:\Users\amell\Documents\geonode\geonode\__init__.py", line 29, in get_version
          import geonode.version
        File "C:\Users\amell\Documents\geonode\geonode\version.py", line 45
          sub += f'.dev{git_changeset}'
                                      ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\amell\documents\geonode_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\amell\appdata\local\temp\tmpvsfkgv' Check the logs for full command output.
    
    (geonode_env) C:\Users\amell\Documents>
```

Comment: That looks like Python 3 code (I'm pretty sure F-Strings didn't exist in Pytthon2) so try using Python 3 for the install

Comment: Thats right, I have installed python 3: :\Users\amell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 but also have C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2, looks like that's is what is causing the problem. I edited the path in system settings, moved 39 above 27 but still same problem

Comment: _geonode_env_ may have a different path of system settings.